# Mongodb - $in analog for querying AND, not OR

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im using $in operator in my query like this:

```
"data.answerId": {
    $in: answers
}
```

`answers` is a plain array.
The result of the query is giving me outcome similar to logical `OR`. And I need similar to logical `AND`.

I've read all possible variants in the `Comparison Query Operators` section of the docs, but can't find anything for my needs.

Comment: try using $all instead of $in.

Comment: @sushantmehta thank you! Submit your answer and I will choose it as a right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $all instead of $in in your case to match all elements in the array answers